# How to replace value of any specific key through shell script

Tags: shell, automation, yaml

I need to replace some value of configmap.yaml and I have to automate it through shell script. How to do this?

In my case, some line of config.YAML file is

```
"ABC_KEY" : "*******"
```

While I am automating the total installation process, it got stuck with an error:

> error: error parsing yamlfiles/configMap.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 22: did not find the expected key"

What I want while I run the shell script to automate the installation process and it applies the config.YAML file, is that it asks me some value of the specific key and I will manually enter the value. Then it should run and complete the automation of installation process

Input YAML file:

```
SECRET_KEY: "******"" 
JWT_KEY: "********" 
SFTP_PWD: "*********"
```

In the shell script I am executing this command:

```
kubectl apply -f yamlfiles/configMap.yaml
```

After running the kubectl command, I want it to ask me the value of those keys so that I can manually enter the value then the apply of configmap will be fulfilled. Is it possible?

Comment: You have to show us the commands you're executing and the YAML file's content for us to be able to comprehend your error. Anyway, did you try using `sed`?

Comment: yaml file :
  SECRET_KEY: "******""
  JWT_KEY: "********"
  SFTP_PWD: "*********"

in shell script i am executing command : kubectl apply -f yamlfiles/configMap.yaml

error : error parsing yamlfiles/configMap.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 22: did not find expected key"

i  want after running the kubectlcommand itwould ask me the value of those key and i will manually enter the value then the apply of configmap will be fulfillef....is it possible ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the relevant information as it is not readable in a comment.

Comment: You do not show the whole YAML file. The error references line 22 when the YAML only has 3 lines. You also need to describe what you want to replace in more detail. Currently, it looks like you want to replace the `"******"` part which is a value; however the error indicates that a *key* is missing. In any case, you need to update the YAML file *before* submitting it to `kubectl` as that expects a finished, valid YAML file.